# Apply a WPF style to a Border within a UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, styles

I have a very simple UserControl, which just consists of a TextBlock contained within a Border element.

Is there a way of applying a style to the TextBlock within the UserControl from the containing window.

I know that I can create a style with..

```
<Style TargetType='TextBlock'>
```

But this applies to all TextBlocks within my window, not just the ones inside my UserControl

So I want to be able to say something like...

```
<Style TargetType='MyUserControl.TextBlock'>
```

Thanks,

Rich.

PS. this is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do!

### ADDITIONAL NOTE

As I was driving home this evening, this was rattling around inside my head, and I thought of a possible solution.. and that's to create a basic sub-class of the TextBlock control, and call it MyTextBlock.. so just have a definition like

```
public class MyTextBlock : TextBlock { }
```

Then, within the usercontrol, use 'MyTextBlock' rather than 'TextBlock'. This will allow me to apply a style to a type of 'MyTextBlock'. Bingo !!!

Maybe this isn't the tidiest way of doing this, but it's very little code, and it works.

However, as I'm fairly new to WPF, I'm quite interested in a more standard way of acheiving this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option if you want to apply a `Style` to all `TextBlocks` inside `MyUserControl` is this

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type my:MyUserControl}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

And if you want to add another `Style` for `MyUserControl` you just have to base it on the default `Style`

```
<Style x:Key="myStyle" TargetType="{x:Type my:MyUserControl}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type my:MyUserControl}}">
    <!-- ... -->
</Style>
```

---

Otherwise, if you want to be able to set a `Style` for some controls inside MyUserControl you can use DependencyProperties. For a `TextBlock` you can have a style called `TextBlockStyle` for example. The `TextBlock` will bind to this `Style` and you can set the `Style` from your window (or wherever you use it). This can also be seen in some controls in the framework, `AutoCompleteBox` in the toolkit for example

```
<toolkit:AutoCompleteBox>
    <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox.TextBoxStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="MaxLength" Value="10"/>
        </Style>
    </toolkit:AutoCompleteBox.TextBoxStyle>
</toolkit:AutoCompleteBox>
```

*MyUserControl.xaml*

```
<Border BorderThickness="1">
    <TextBlock Style="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},
                               Path=TextBlockStyle}"
               Text="Test"/>
</Border>
```

*MyUserControl.xaml.cs*

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public static DependencyProperty TextBlockStyleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("TextBlockStyle",
                                    typeof(Style),
                                    typeof(MyUserControl));
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Style TextBlockStyle
    {
        get { return (Style)GetValue(TextBlockStyleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextBlockStyleProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

And then you set the `Style` when you declare your instance in markup for example

```
<my:MyUserControl>
    <my:MyUserControl.TextBlockStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
        </Style>
    </my:MyUserControl.TextBlockStyle>
</my:MyUserControl>
```

**Update**

To set this on resource level you can add a default style for `MyUserControl`, in the window resources or App.xaml for example

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type my:MyUserControl}">
        <Setter Property="TextBlockStyle">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
                </Style>
            </Setter.Value>                
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Hi Meleak, I have tried your solution, and understand where you're coming from, but I can't work out the syntax if I want to apply this style at the resource level, i.e. not have to spell it out every time I include this control.

Comment: @RichS: See my update. Is that what you're looking for or did I missunderstand your question? If you want it to be application wide, add it to app.xaml instead

Comment: Yep, you hit the nail on the head.. I was missing the <Setter.Value> part of it.. you're a star, thanks @Maleak

Comment: Incidentally, did you see my 'Additional Note' on my main question ? I quite like that solution, but I guess it's more c# than WPF.

Comment: Yes, I did see it and like you said, I will absolutely work. If you only want to apply one `Style` to all `TextBlocks` inside the MyUserControl you also have another option which I added to my answer. And if you want to apply another `Style` to MyUserControl you just have to base it on the default `Style`

Comment: @Maleak The first part of your 'Update 2' was exactly what I was looking for !! :-)

Comment: @RichS: Ah ok :) I re-structured my answer a bit so the most relevant part to your question came on top. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you can change.

First, you can use Styles with a resource key.  So you would write:

```
<Style x:Key="myTextStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock">
```

Then in order for a TextBox to have this style applied to it, it would need to specify:

```
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource myTextStyle" />
```

If you do not want to modify the UserControl and you just want to apply the style in an element that is nesting the UserControl inside it, keep in mind that you can declare styles in the resource dictionary of a nested element.  When you place your UserControl, consider doing this:

```
<local:UserControl>
    <local:UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            ...
        </Style>
    </local:UserControl.Resources>
</local:UserControl>
```

Comment: Hi @Moozhe, the second part of your answer was very close to what I was looking for.. thanks !

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways I can think of doing this:

One is in code in the containing window by explicitly setting the style

`MyUserControl.TextBlockName.Style = FindResource("TextBlockStyle") as Style;`

The other way would be to create a [DependencyProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx) to hold the Textblock style and apply the style on the TextBlock element when the `DependencyProperty` is changed.

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for a way of setting the style for the textblocks held within all instances of my usercontrol, I didn't really want to be setting is explicitly for each instance. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

if you have something like this in your xaml:

```
 <xmlns:local = "myCustonUserControl">
```

you can use this as a style definition:

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyUserControl}">
```

hope that helps!

Comment: This will allow you to set a style to the whole control and not individual elements within the control.